# Moved files to trash when booted with Linux CD, can I recover them?

Tags: live-cd, trash

This sounds really silly... I burnt an ISO of Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS to a disk and booted up the Live CD with the first option (try Ubuntu without installing). I mounted an external hard drive and moved a folder to trash. I then emptied the trash.
Can this folder be recovered? Does the Ubuntu disk use the hard drive of the the machine it booted on to hold temporary files so it may be there? Or will I have to run a recovery tool on the external hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a recovery tool suited to the file system type your HDD uses (Fat, NTFS, ext4, ...).

If you are still in the live-session, search the package manager for scrounge-ntfs if you are using ntfs for your partition. You can install by opening the terminal and typing

```
sudo apt-get install scrounge-ntfs
```

It's synopsis says

> Scrounge NTFS is a data recovery program for NTFS filesystems. It reads each
>   block of the hard disk and try to rebuild the original filesystem tree into
>   a directory.
>
> This package is useful in forensics investigations.

There are other options. I use synaptic to search the package manager for relevant software:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Other options would include extundelete for ext4 partitions

```
sudo apt-get install man extundelete
```

Search synaptic to find a suitable tool.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am nolonger in the session. When you say HDD, do you mean the external one I deleted the folder from or the one that is in the machine I booked the Live CD on? I keep thinking the Live CD uses the machines disk drive to store temporary files.

Comment: The HDD you mounted.  You can boot the live disk again, and install the tools.  As long as you haven't been using the computer since you powered down the live disk, you are in with a chance of recoverring data.  Otherwise, the space will be used by the computer and your data may be unrecoverable

Comment: Ok thanks I will follow the instructions. I have used the computer, but not with the external HDD connected (where the folder originally was) so I should be ok?

Comment: That's good.  mount it as read only when you plug it in - you may get your data back after all

Comment: Thanks it worked, thank you, I have accepted your answer. Can I clarify if the Live CD stores temporary files on the machines HDD?

Comment: Live CDs are not permitted to just store files to your HDD.  Here's a link you may find informative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898301/where-is-data-on-a-non-persistant-live-cd-stored.  Feel free to join us in the discord https://discord.gg/FZvs6j